# Reduce variance by increasing complexity of NN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, references

Everything I 've read so far point to the opposite,  but are there any cases or papers that suggest that this is possible or is it a categorical no?

Answer (score 2):

In general, variance increases as complexity increases, and it holds for any model---not just a neural network.

Variance refers to the variance of the model coefficients/ weights over different training datasets.  These training sets differ really essentially with respect to noise alone.  A model with more complexity necessarily has higher ability to over-interpret noise in the training set.  Hence the coefficients will be more different on one training set relative to another for a comlex model than for a simple model.  Hence more complexity leads to more variance in coefficients over different training sets.

Suppose we had a neural network that outputs 1 regardless of input. Regardless of the training data, we get 1.  So, the "coefficient" (which doesn't really exist) has 0 variance over training sets.  Conversely if we memorize a training set because the network has maximum complexity, the coefficients must vary over training sets to a great degree. Again in theory I don't think there is anything surprising you could find along this continuum.

However, what if there were a model with n coefficients that happens to be too simple to capture a certain relationship in the data.  With n+1 coefficients, it is able to capture that relationship. If the relationship is definitive between the input and response, perhaps then the variance of the coefficients would decrease moving from n to n+1?  Consider a sphere dataset.  With 2 learnable parameters for a 3D input (fix one at 0), it is not possible to determine whether a point is inside or outside of the sphere; the only points that would be perfectly classified would be ones on the vertical line in the center of the sphere.  With 3 parameters for a 3D input, however (we now have 3 parameters that can vary), it should be trivial for the model to learn whether a point is in or out of the sphere.  I think the variance of the coefficients of the 2 parameter model might be larger than the variance of the coefficients of the 3 parameter model in this case?  Although actually the 2 parameter model might still have lower variance because it simply learns the line each time.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to update the question which much more information when I get time, however to you last point (n could still have lower variance...) I was referring to variance from train/val/test set, in which case you could get lower variance in n+1 model. What puzzled me though, is that from the ML courses I did, is that small network (n in your example) would suffer from high bias.